# Horizontal or Vertical Layout for Confirmation Screen on mobile?

Tags: mobile-application, ux-field

Recently, I encountered this problem. There are two options for a redesign, one would be to list the information vertically aligned with its label, the other is to show the information side by side with the label.

There are a few competing design rules here and I don't know which direction to take.

- A is more easy to scan, but B provides more information on each field by showing its label
- A seems aesthetically more pleasing, but B might be more consistent when editing individual fields

Which direction is better for user experience?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Knowing that it's for mobile screens, based on [Visual Hierarchies](https://admiral.digital/what-is-visual-hierarchy-and-why-is-it-important/), I would choose the one with the least complicated reading for the user.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I thing option A is obvious. And as Steve Krug says in his book... "Dont Make me thing..." Everyone understands it. Avoid the option B, becaouse in my opinion it has so many informations that it confuses me.